# Can't find package where "cvLoad" is located in JavaCV?

Tags: javacv, javacpp

I try a sample code for face detection but the method `cvLoad` is not found, even if I imported `org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.*` :

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.FlyCapture2.Image;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.CvMemStorage;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.cvClearMemStorage;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.CvHaarClassifierCascade;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.*;


/**
 *
 * @author LEVALLOIS
 */
public class FaceDetect {

    // Create memory for calculations
    CvMemStorage storage = null;

    // Create a new Haar classifier
    CvHaarClassifierCascade classifier = null;

    // List of classifiers
    String[] classifierName = {
        "./classifiers/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml",
        "./classifiers/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml",
        "./classifiers/haarcascade_profileface.xml"};

    public FaceDetect() {
        // Allocate the memory storage
        storage = CvMemStorage.create();

        // Load the HaarClassifierCascade
        classifier = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(classifierName[0]));

        // Make sure the cascade is loaded
        if (classifier.isNull()) {
            System.err.println("Error loading classifier file");
        }
    }

    public boolean find(Image value) {
        // Clear the memory storage which was used before
        cvClearMemStorage(storage);

        if (!classifier.isNull()) {
            // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
            CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(value, classifier,
                    storage, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

            // Get the number of faces found.
            int total = faces.total();
            if (total > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>

Error: FaceDetect.java:[39,50] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method cvLoad(java.lang.String)
```

Help?

Comment: The cvLoad method is not present in the 1.4.4 version of the package. Reverting to 1.4.2 worked,  but I would be curious to know how it would work in 1.4.4

Comment: It's gone with OpenCV 4.0, please switch to the C++ API.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes  manually writing the import statements works instead of depending on the ide shortcut Ctrl+shft+o

so add the below import statement manually

```
 import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.cvLoadImage;
```